# Tool for Google Translate HTML, keeping tags

Tags: html, wordpress, google-translate, language-translation

I have got 30 HTML pages written in Czech and I need to translate them easily and cheaply into English and German.

So I'm looking for a tool where I put HTML content, it translates the texts with Google translate (or other service) and **outputs the same HTML structure but with translated texts**. So no tags or classes stripped whatsoever.

Is there such a service/tool/way? I can do it manually page by page, I don't need an API. I tried Google Translation Toolkit, but it strips HTML5 tags such as `<article>`. It works better in a common translate.google.com service, but it puts the bubbles with original texts in the HTML. The website runs Wordpress, but I don't think there's a such tool specially for Wordpress.

Comment: i posted my solution in [Prohibit the translation of pieces of text in Google Translate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52668)

Answer (score 0):

quick and cheap trick:
`<footer>` will be translated, but `<0footer>` - NOT. So whatever tag you using, doing `<0whatever>` will not be translated too.

Answer (score 0):

ViliuL's answer works great. Find and replace in the following order:

```
find: </
replace: </0
find: <
replace: <0
```

**Translate**

```
find: 0
replace: ""
find <" "/" "
replace </
```